# GCC - Missing braces around initializer

Tags: c, gcc, c11

There are lots of questions about this warning, but none of the ones I've tried seem to make the warning go away.

This is what I have:

```
typedef struct {
    union {
        float data[16];
        float col_row[4][4];
    };
} matrix44;

// ...

matrix44 result = {0};
```

I'm trying to initialize the struct to zero, but can't get it to not give an error about it. This is being compiled as C11.

I've also tried other variations, some ridiculous:

```
matrix44 result = {{0}};
matrix44 result = { {0}, {0} };
matrix44 result = { {0}, { {0}, {0} } };
```

But of course they all give the warning.

If I reduce the struct to just the single-dimensional `data` array, then I can initialize it with `{{0}}` without warning. But reducing it to the two-dimensional `col_row` array still gives the warning either way.

Is there a right way to do this that avoids the warning? Or is the warning incorrect in this case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use:

```
matrix44 result = {{{0}}};
```

to avoid warnings with `gcc`. The first pair of `{}` for the structure, the  second pair for the union and the  third pair for the array.

Comment: Ah, so that's how it breaks down. That did the trick, thanks!